# What happened to a tzarua when Bnei Yisrael moved?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tzaraas-negaim, bamidbar-numbers-book-of, miriam, parashat-metzora

[Bamidbar 12:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.12.15?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0) tells us that Bnei Yisrael waited for Miriam when she got tzaraat, which seems to be an anomaly:

> וַתִּסָּגֵ֥ר מִרְיָ֛ם מִח֥וּץ לַֽמַּחֲנֶ֖ה שִׁבְעַ֣ת יָמִ֑ים וְהָעָם֙ לֹ֣א נָסַ֔ע עַד־הֵאָסֵ֖ף מִרְיָֽם׃
>
> “So Miriam was shut out of camp seven days; and the people did not march on until Miriam was readmitted.”

What did they do when other people got tzaraat and were exiled from the camp - did they travel and leave the exiled tzarua behind?

Comment: Why behind? Presumably they walked along just outside the camp

Comment: Great question. The pasuk (13:5-6) states "and the priest shall look on him on the seventh day"- this is not possible if the people with tzaraat would be left behind.

Comment: See the gemoro in sota and artscroll of how long miriam waited for moshe in his basket and how that adds up to seven days waiting for miriam.  And my addition is that if Moshe would not have prayed for her how long she would have had tsoraas.